# Facebook's Open Graph localized actions

Tags: facebook-graph-api, localization

I've got a Facebook app with open graph custom story, which has been reviewed and approved.

The app details are localized in English US (Primary language) and Italian.

I want now to localize all the open graph's strings in italian. I translated all of them by myself, so they are approved.

In the dashboard (at https://www.facebook.com/translations/admin/dashboard/?app={APP_ID}) I got:

Approval/Publishing/Translation Progress: 0%
Publish: Published

How is it possible the 0% of published strings? Indeed, when I publish actions with the app, they still are in English on my timeline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a confirmed bug about this in the facebook bug platform.

Check this out: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/390205151183880/?search_id

Once it's solved the translations would return to it's normal functionality.